# Force page to scroll to top doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to force the browser to go to top of the page when the user click "back" in the browser instead of show the original position from where the user had come. Example: user scroll in page1 about 1500px, the click on a link and goes to page2; now he clicks the back button, and the browser come back to the page1 at about 1500px from the top. I would that the user would be back on the top of the page. So I've put this script in the pages:

```
$(window).load(function(){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0);});
```

It works fine in Firefox, but doesn't work in Google Chrome.

Why? Can someone suggest me a better code or a better solution?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: have you tried using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo ?

Comment: I've tested your suggestion but doesn't work, thanks anyway.